# Touch is not working in the canvas fabric.js on mobiles browsers

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to select rect object when clicking on t-shirt image.

Please check below link. I want to do something like this.

http://bwcmultimedia.com/E/dtooladvance/

this is working fine on computer, but on mobile browsers touch is not working. please tell me how it work in phones browser using touch .

Thanks
Rahul

Comment: Could you please share some source code of what you've already tried so far?

Comment: please check my website http://bwcmultimedia.com/E/dtooladvance in tool.js

Comment: Use a custom build of fabric or if you are using npm list this at scripts "postinstall": "npm explore fabric -- npm run build -- build.js modules=ALL requirejs exclude=accessors"